# How to associate Kentico changes from REST API or External Application to a staging task group

Tags: console-application, kentico

How to associate Kentico changes from REST API or External Application (*like windows console application*) to a staging task group

```
static void Main ( string [ ] args )
{
    UserInfo userInfo = UserInfoProvider.GetUserInfo ( "User1" );
    using ( new CMSActionContext ( userInfo ) )
    {
        TreeProvider treeProvider = new TreeProvider ( userInfo );
        NodeSelectionParameters nodeSelectionParameters = new NodeSelectionParameters
        {
            AliasPath = "Path"
        };
        TreeNode parentPage = treeProvider.SelectSingleNode ( nodeSelectionParameters );

        TreeNode newPage = TreeNode.New ( "Class", treeProvider );
        newPage.DocumentName = "Test Title";
        newPage.DocumentCulture = "en-us";
        newPage.DocumentUrlPath = "Path";

        newPage.Insert ( parentPage );
    }
}
```

The above code is properly creating the document and the staging tasks with the user context. How can I associate the staging tasks for this document to a staging task group?

Comment: Can you give some more detailed information on what you're changing and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the **SynchronizationActionContext** class to associate API changes to a staging task group.

```
    static void Main ( string [ ] args )
    {
        List<TaskGroupInfo> taskGroups = TaskGroupInfoProvider.GetTaskGroups ( ).WhereEquals ( "TaskGroupCodeName", "MyTaskGroup" ).ToList ( );
        using ( new SynchronizationActionContext ( ) { TaskGroups = taskGroups } )
        {
            UserInfo userInfo = UserInfoProvider.GetUserInfo ( "User1" );
            using ( new CMSActionContext ( userInfo ) )
            {
                TreeProvider treeProvider = new TreeProvider ( userInfo );
                NodeSelectionParameters nodeSelectionParameters = new NodeSelectionParameters
                {
                    AliasPath = "Path"
                };
                TreeNode parentPage = treeProvider.SelectSingleNode ( nodeSelectionParameters );

                TreeNode newPage = TreeNode.New ( "Class", treeProvider );
                newPage.DocumentName = "Test Title";
                newPage.DocumentCulture = "en-us";
                newPage.DocumentUrlPath = "Path";

                newPage.Insert ( parentPage );
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First I'd look to make sure that the objects that you are changing are in the list of items supported by content staging.  you can see that list here: [Content staging - What can be synchronized](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/deploying-websites/content-staging#Contentstaging-Whatcanbesynchronized)

So long as you are ultimately using Kentico's API, and [Content Staging is enabled](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/deploying-websites/content-staging/configuring-content-staging), then Kentico should be creating these tasks for you.  If you're updating the Kentico database directly without the API, you're probably going to run into trouble and might need to manually create staging tasks or [use the API to perform synchronisation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/miscellaneous-custom-development-tasks/synchronizing-content-using-the-api).